# Amazon Load Balancer sticky sessions configuration for jsessionid in URL

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services, load-balancing, jsessionid

I currently trying to setup Amazon Load Balancer for Tomcat workers, but I faced one problem.

I'm using sticky sessions and cookie `JSESSIONID` is available for most of the requests. But some requests have session information in URL, like this:

http://myserver.com/contextPath/someAction;jsessionid=BA6853C23F795BD5EEDAEA996E601BB8

And it does not work (and request is forwarded to the wrong worker).

**Does AWS Load Balancer support `jsessionid` in the URL? If no, than maybe you know some workarounds?**

With Apache + mod_proxy_balancer I can, for example, define it like this:

```
ProxyPassMatch /.* balancer://mycluster stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid
```

Comment: Did you ever find a workaround for this? It seems unfortunate that all of my url rewriting is obsolete just because of the sticky session feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AWS's Elastic Load Balancer does not support URL-based session stickiness.

Be sure to check that you've set the ELB's stickiness policy.

Also, ELB's stickiness doesn't actually look at the value of any cookie except for its own called "AWSELB". When you configure a cookie-based stickiness policy you're really configuring the *lifetime* of the stickiness to follow the *lifetime* of the specified cookie - but the actual server assignment is controlled by the AWSELB cookie.

Comment: Yeah... I also contacted AWS support and they "advised" me to rewrite my application :) (very helpful). Thanks for explaining `AWSELB` cookie specifics - I was wondering why LB always adds it's own cookies even if I set stickiness policy to "Application managed".